# how to get "properties" through gdbus

Tags: api, gdbus

Can anybody tell me where I can find documentation on how to use gdbus call to get information from the system?

I am following APIs here: 
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-ModemManager1-Modem.Command

and I want to read for example:  
Model 
Revision 
State 
PowerState

etc.

I was wondering how to create a call to get the "properties" out of the modem through gdbus

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DBus Properties are accessible through method:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get (in STRING interface_name,
                                     in STRING property_name, 
                                     out VARIANT value);
```

or

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll (in STRING interface_name,
                                        out DICT<STRING,VARIANT> props)
```

To get Model, for example, you could use *dbus-send* like so:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.ModemManager1 --print-reply \
/path/to/Modem/object org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
string:'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem' string:'Model'
```

where /path/to/Modem/object will be something like `/org/freedesktop.ModemManager1/Modems/#` and # is the unique integer identifier for the modem you want to get the information for. 
For more information on dbus-send check the documentation https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-send.1.html